# UILabel vertical size is larger using font scaling, extra padding inserted

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, autolayout, uilabel

When using font scaling on a multiline UILabel, the intrinsic content size is larger as it needs to be

**How to get a better fitting size?**

[image]

[image: Settings for the label]

Comment: What is the result that you are going for?

Comment: remove the top / bottom padding in the second label and have a size that better fits content

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation UILabel (dynamicSizeWidth)

- (void)resizeToStretch  {
    float width = [self expectedWidth];
    CGRect newFrame = [self frame];
    newFrame.size.width = width;
    [self setFrame:newFrame];
}

- (float)expectedWidth{
    [self setNumberOfLines:1];

    CGSize maximumLabelSize = CGSizeMake(CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds), CGFLOAT_MAX);

    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [[self text] sizeWithFont:[self font] 
                                            constrainedToSize:maximumLabelSize
                                            lineBreakMode:[self lineBreakMode]]; 
    return expectedLabelSize.width;
}

@end
```

Beyond iOS6 you can use Autolayout, set number of lines to 0 and the framework will resize your label appropriately to fit your text.